# Email With Rails 3 and Heroku Net::SMTPSyntaxError: 501 Syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, email

As the title says I'm trying to get a simple email working with Heroku and Rails 3.  I'm using this Heroku guide:  http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp

Here is my code:

I generated a mailer that looks like this:

```
class Invite < ActionMailer::Base
  def signup_notification(user)
    recipients "#{user.first_name} <#{user.email}>"
    from       "Test"
    subject    "Please activate your new account"
    sent_on    Time.now
    body       :var => 'testing'
  end
end
```

I have a view in `app/views/invite/signup_notification.rhtml`

**UPDATE:** I see that `.rhtml` doesn't work with Rails 3 so I just tried `.html.erb` but I got the *same error*.

```
Your account has been created.
Username: 
Password: 
Visit this url to activate your account:
```

Then in the Heroku console I did this:

```
user = User.new(:first_name => 'Me', :email => 'me@hotmail.com', :login => 'me', :password => '1234')
```

and then this:

```
Invite.deliver_signup_notification(user)
```

and if get this error:

```
Net::SMTPSyntaxError: 501 Syntax error
  /user/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:930:in `check_response`
  /user/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:899:in `getok`
  /user/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:828:in `mailfrom`
  /user/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:653:in `sendmail`
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your `from` is invalid. Try from 'test@example.com' instead.

Comment: the follow up question is how can you know this from the generic message 'Net::SMTPSyntaxError: 501 Syntax error'? Is there a more specific message some where else?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to show custom string in `from` then you can use something like

```
from  "Test <info@domain.com>"
```

and when you send email title would be Test

Answer (score 1):

The Heroku guide is for Rails < 3.0.  Use the [Rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) for 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

`Net::SMTPSyntaxError 501` error is thrown if you have bad sender address.
Sender address should be an email address. Any fake email will also do. like: abc@fakemail.com

Comment: `Net::SMTPSyntaxError 501` is thrown for both `from` and `to` email address?