# Net::SMTPSyntaxError · 501 Invalid command or cannot parse from address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp

I have read some discussion, Q&A about the error w/c is thrown if sender email is invalid,

but I'm not sure if
this error `Net::SMTPSyntaxError · 501` is for both invalid email `from` & `to`.

Comment: Maybe help this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998758/email-with-rails-3-and-heroku-netsmtpsyntaxerror-501-syntax-error

Answer (score 1):

Net::SMTPSyntaxError 501 error is thrown if you have bad sender address. Sender address should be an email address. Any fake email will also do. like: abc@fakemail.com